# Reading gziped file line by line

Tags: c++, boost, zlib

I have gz file that was created in c# with GZipStream.

I'm trying to read it in c++ line by line.

Here's the code I'm using

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <boost/iostreams/filtering_streambuf.hpp>
#include <boost/iostreams/copy.hpp>
#include <boost/iostreams/filter/zlib.hpp>
#include <sstream>


int main()
{
    using namespace std;

    ifstream file(R"(path-to-my-file.gz)", ios_base::in | ios_base::binary);
    boost::iostreams::filtering_streambuf<boost::iostreams::input> in;
    in.push(boost::iostreams::zlib_decompressor());
    in.push(file);
    std::istream incoming(&in);
    string line;
    while(true)
    {
        getline(incoming, line);
        cout << "line:"<<line << endl;
        cin.get();
    }
}
```

I have downloaded zlib from https://www.zlib.net/ and re-built boost with `b2 -sZLIB_SOURCE="G:\c++source\zlib-1.2.11"`.

The problem is that the `line` is always empty. What's wrong with the code above?

Comment: You are not doing any error handling on `getline()`. `while(true) { getline(incoming, line); ...}` should be changed to `while(getline(incoming, line)) { ... }`  Also, zlib and gzip are two different formats.  Did you try `boost::iostreams::gzip_decompressor` yet?

Comment: yes, I did try gzip_decompressor, and that works

Comment: You should be posting that as an answer then

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was, I was using boost::iostreams::zlib_decompressor() instead of boost::iostreams::gzip_decompressor()